# BeautifulSoup is not getting all data, only some

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def trade_spider(max_pages):
page = 0
while page <= max_pages:
    url = 'http://orangecounty.craigslist.org/search/foa?s=' + str(page * 100)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'hdrlnk'}):
        href = 'http://orangecounty.craigslist.org/' + link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        print title
        #print href
        get_single_item_data(href)
    page += 1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('section', {'id':'postingbody'}):
        print item_name.string



trade_spider(1)
```

I am trying to crawl craigslist (for practice), http://orangecounty.craigslist.org/search/foa?s=0 in particular. I have it right now set to print the title of the entry and the description of the entry. The issue is that although the title correctly prints for every object listed, the description is listed as "None" for most of them, even though there is clearly a description. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the `.string`, [get the text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) of the posting body (worked for me):

```
item_name.get_text(strip=True)
```

As a side note, your script has a blocking "nature", you may speed things up dramatically by switching to [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](http://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.  Just change `item_name.string` to `item_name.text`